# Extract row from a data frame and make it a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0,2,5,3], [3,1,4,2], [1,3,5,2], [5,1,3,4], [4,2,5,1], [2,3,5,1]]))
df
```

Now, I need first row of data frame and make it another data frame

like

```
    row
0    0
1    2
2    5
3    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) like:

```
df1 = df.iloc[0].to_frame('row')
```

For `Series`:

```
s = df.iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use double `[[ ]]` and transpose it:

```
>>> df.iloc[[0]].T
   0
0  0
1  2
2  5
3  3
```